# Coding scheme for redundant levels in a linear model

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, categorical-encoding

I want to get the main effects of IV1, IV2 and IV3 as well as the interaction effect of IV2*IV3 on the outcome for the following three independent variables in a repeated measures anlysis:

- IV1 indicates whether a stimulus was shown (1) or not (0)
- IV2 represents 3 characteristics of the stimulus (from which only one is present at a time)
- IV3 represents 2 other, theoretically distinct, characteristics of the stimulus

With the representation below I would have to introduce artificial and redundant levels for IV2 (level 4) and IV3 (level 3) which actually cannot exist, i.e. there are no characteristics of the stimulus when it is not shown.

```
IV1  IV2  IV3    
1    1    2
1    2    2
0    4    3  
1    3    1
0    4    3
0    4    3
1    2    1 
1    2    2
and so on ...
```

What is the best coding scheme for this kind of problems in general (or using R)? Do I even need three independent variables or can I overcome this with smart contrast coding?